# UniqueBody is not very unique?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm trying to read the content of an email in HTML. My problem though, is that my body is not very unique though I'm loading the `EmailMessageSchema.UniqueBody`.

Here's my expected solution:

```
var props = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, 
    EmailMessageSchema.UniqueBody,
    EmailMessageSchema.Subject,
    EmailMessageSchema.To,
    EmailMessageSchema.From
    /*Futher properties if needed*/);

props.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.HTML;

var message = EmailMessage.Bind(subscription.Service, item.ItemId, props);

// Should be unique
var uniqueBody = message.UniqueBody.Text;
```

When debugging and investigate my `uniqueBody` variable, I can clearly see that this is **not** unique. It takes the entire body of the email prior to the current email (*as the current email is a response, i wouldn't expect to get the content of the email responded to*).

I'm not sure I understand the concept of the `EmailMessageSchema.UniqueBody` property, or perhaps I'm simply doing something wrong?

So, how do I get the unique body of a reply email, without it's parents body?

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0de23e0-e4a4-4457-a0a5-1c6d8c438d0d/how-do-i-get-uniquebody-from-incoming-email-in-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Comment: Added a reply a few days ago, any comments?

Comment: I am no longer working with this, so I'll just leave this SO here for future references.

Answer (score 8):

### Explanation:

As defined in the documentation ([link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.uniquebody.aspx?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)), `UniqueBody` is:

> the body part that is unique to the conversation that this item is
> part of

The main part of this sentence is the idea of `conversation`: it is a notion from your mailbox, not from the message. As a consequence, the field `UniqueBody` will give you only the newest part of a message after an initial one.

For the 1st message, even if it includes several messages (due to a forward or reply), `UniqueBody` will contain everything.

---

### Sample:

I used my external address "mailA" to forward a message from "mailB" to "mailEWS" which will be the address where I query emails with EWS. I added a comment on this forward, named "Forwarded email sample".

Here is what I got when getting the message in "mailEWS":

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div dir="ltr">
               <span dir="ltr">
                  Forwarded email sample
                  <div>
                     <br>
                     <div>
                        Test from MailB &lt;<a href="mailto:mailA@gmail.com" target="_blank">mailA@gmail.com</a>&gt;:<br>
                        <div style="margin:0 0 0 0.8ex;padding-left:1ex;border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC;">Dear user,<br>
                           <br>
                           Content of initial email from mailB<br>
                           <br>
                           Sincerely,<br>
                           Test<br>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I got the original message and the comment on the forward.

Then:

- mailEWS replies (text = "reply 1"
- mailA replies on that reply (reply text is "Reply from external address")

So I got a new message in my mailEWS mailbox, when getting the UniqueBody with EWS:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div dir="ltr"><span dir="ltr">Reply from external address</span></div>
            <div><br>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I get only the newest part of the message in the conversation, not all the previous replies (but those items are in `Body` field)

Answer (score 0):

We can get the Unique body by using below code.

```
var props = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, 
    EmailMessageSchema.UniqueBody,
    EmailMessageSchema.Subject,
    EmailMessageSchema.To,
    EmailMessageSchema.From

props.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.HTML;

var message = EmailMessage.Bind(subscription.Service, item.ItemId, props);

// Should be unique
var uniqueBody = message.UniqueBody.Text;
```